# Flutter Unhandled error type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>'

Tags: flutter, flutter-http

When calling `http.get` using the Flutter http package, the following exception gets thrown:

`Unhandled Exception: Unhandled error type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>' occurred in bloc Instance of 'AccountsBloc'.`

The code which throws the exception

```
final response = await http.get(
  serverConfig.url,
  headers: _getHeaders(username, password),
);

Map<String, dynamic> _getHeaders(String username, String password) {
  return {
    "apikey": serverConfig.apiKey,
    "action": "login",
    "user": username,
    "pass": password
  };
}
```

It seems that `_getHeaders()` is causing this problem, when it's called according to the console output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
Map<String, String> _getHeaders(String username, String password) {
  return {
    "apikey": serverConfig.apiKey,
    "action": "login",
    "user": username,
    "pass": password
  };
}
```